# Trying to install clang-16 using MacPorts, but clangd along with others aren't set?

Tags: macports

I am having slight difficulties installing clang-16 from MacPorts.

I want to use the lastest version which is 16 at this point instead of the version that ships with Xcode Command Line Tools.

which `clang`

```
$ which clang
/usr/bin/clang
```

and which `clangd`

```
$ which clangd
/usr/bin/clangd
```

Then I install `clang-16` from MacPorts

```
$ sudo port install clang-16
```

All good so far.

```
$ port select --list clang
Available versions for clang:
    mp-clang-16 (active)
    none
```

Just to confirm.

```
$ which clang
/opt/local/bin/clang
```

But `clangd` isn't updated to use the newly installed `clangd-mp-16`

```
$ which clangd
/usr/bin/clangd
```

I guess I could maybe `sudo port select --set clangd clangd-mp-16`.
How do I make sure that everything related to clang-16 is available and being used?
The list is quite long. Am I supposed to set all those manually? That seems error-prone.

```
$ ls /opt/local/bin/*clang*
/opt/local/bin/clang                            /opt/local/bin/clang-mp-16
/opt/local/bin/clang++                          /opt/local/bin/clang-offload-bundler-mp-16
/opt/local/bin/clang++-mp-16                    /opt/local/bin/clang-offload-packager-mp-16
/opt/local/bin/clang-apply-replacements         /opt/local/bin/clang-pseudo-mp-16
/opt/local/bin/clang-apply-replacements-mp-16   /opt/local/bin/clang-query
/opt/local/bin/clang-change-namespace-mp-16     /opt/local/bin/clang-query-mp-16
/opt/local/bin/clang-check                      /opt/local/bin/clang-refactor-mp-16
/opt/local/bin/clang-check-mp-16                /opt/local/bin/clang-rename
/opt/local/bin/clang-cl                         /opt/local/bin/clang-rename-mp-16
/opt/local/bin/clang-cl-mp-16                   /opt/local/bin/clang-reorder-fields-mp-16
/opt/local/bin/clang-cpp-mp-16                  /opt/local/bin/clang-repl-mp-16
/opt/local/bin/clang-doc-mp-16                  /opt/local/bin/clang-scan-deps-mp-16
/opt/local/bin/clang-extdef-mapping-mp-16       /opt/local/bin/clang-tblgen-mp-16
/opt/local/bin/clang-format                     /opt/local/bin/clang-tidy
/opt/local/bin/clang-format-mp-16               /opt/local/bin/clang-tidy-mp-16
/opt/local/bin/clang-include-cleaner-mp-16      /opt/local/bin/clangd-mp-16
/opt/local/bin/clang-include-fixer-mp-16        /opt/local/bin/clangd-xpc-test-client-mp-16
/opt/local/bin/clang-linker-wrapper-mp-16       /opt/local/bin/git-clang-format-mp-16
/opt/local/bin/clang-move-mp-16                 /opt/local/bin/run-clang-tidy-mp-16
```

I just wanna use clang installed using MacPorts and not the `xcode-select` version. If someone could point me in the right direction I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: The best way is to edit the file that does the build to use the relevany clang executable and version don't rely on your path - especially as Xcode and other IDES might not run things through a shell.

Comment: Thanks. So that means it needs to setup for every single build/project? 

Comment: Well yes but you can simplify this by using include files in your build scripts. (It does depends on build system how easy that is)